# Keep one window always on top of another programatically

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a (non-commercial) program which creates two windows, one displaying scrolling text, which you type into in order to issue commands. The other displays assorted complex graphics in response to those commands. The graphics information is so detailed an complex that it needs to take up the entirety of a large monitor. I usually position the text window on a second monitor so there is never any thought given to which window is "on top".

I now wish to enable a (non-technical) friend to use my program and he wants it to work on a single monitor. What I'd like to do is position the (small) text window on top of the graphics window in one corner, but somehow arrange that the text window remains on top of the graphics window, even when the graphics window is selected. Can this be done, and if so how?

Comment: `SetWindowPos(hwndTarget, HWND_TOP, 0,0, 0,0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE)` should do it.

Comment: @enhzflep That won't stop the window being behind other windows. It just brings to to the top now.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan - it's obviously time for bed. What a silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the window you wish to be on top be owned by the other window. An owned window is always above its owner. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) says:

> **Owned Windows**
>
> An overlapped or pop-up window can be owned by another overlapped or
>   pop-up window. Being owned places several constraints on a window.
>
> - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.
> - The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed.
> - An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.
>
> Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child
>   window cannot be an owner window. An application creates an owned
>   window by specifying the owner's window handle as the hwndParent
>   parameter of CreateWindowEx when it creates a window with the
>   WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_POPUP style. The hwndParent parameter must
>   identify an overlapped or pop-up window. If hwndParent identifies a
>   child window, the system assigns ownership to the top-level parent
>   window of the child window. After creating an owned window, an
>   application cannot transfer ownership of the window to another window.
>
> Dialog boxes and message boxes are owned windows by default. An
>   application specifies the owner window when calling a function that
>   creates a dialog box or message box.
>
> An application can use the GetWindow function with the GW_OWNER flag
>   to retrieve a handle to a window's owner.

So, specify the owner of a window with the `hWndParent` arguments of `CreateWindowEx`. The documentation is a bit hard to follow. It says:

> **hWndParent** [in, optional]
>
> A handle to the parent or owner window of the window being created. To create a child window or an owned window, supply a valid window handle. This parameter is optional for pop-up windows.

What this is getting at is that the parameter is overloaded. For pop-up windows, this parameter specifies the owner. And when you wish to create an unowned window pass `NULL`. That's what it means by the parameter being optional for pop-up windows. For child windows, you pass the parent of the window in this parameter.

Now, in your case, you want to create an owned pop-up window, and so pass the owner in this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the graphics window as owner. This is the same `CreateWindow` argument as parent for a child window. May I suggest that you also provide some means of making the text window more or less transparent.