# Window stays always on top of other windows after Alt+Tab

Tags: winapi

I'm creating a window in the following way:

```cpp
m_handle = CreateWindowExA(
            WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
            WINDOW_CLASS, "Window",
            WS_POPUP,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The window should be on top of other windows, but if the user presses <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to switch to another application on the same monitor, he expects that this topmost window will be hidden, but it doesn't happen.

How can I hide this topmost window?

Comment: You want this window to only be on top of other windows that belong to your program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep one window always on top of another programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441645/keep-one-window-always-on-top-of-another-programatically)

Comment: You are creating a topmost window, and then you wonder why it is staying on top? Weird. Since [`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` prevents this topmost window from becoming the foreground window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles), you are probably looking for [how to detect when the foreground windows changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876151/) so you can then hide your window after it is displayed.

Comment: Does It mean removing topmost style? As far as *Win32API* concerned, *SetWindowPos* can do the job.